# How can I add legends to different map layers in Mapbox GL JS?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, legend, mapbox-gl-js

I am building a web map with multiple toggleable layers using Mapbox GL JS. The web map contains 3 separate parts:

1. Map layers (Mapbox tilesets)
2. Legends
3. Pop-ups

There are two legends built using HTML/CSS that are specific to each map layer:

**Layer 1**: *Raster map of lung cancer incidence*

- **Legend** = *lunginc-legend*

**Layer 2**: *Vector map of percent minority*

- **Legend** = *minority-legend*

I am able to get the legends to appear on the web map, but I would like each legend to only be visible when its associated map layer is visible (and stacked if more than one layer with a legend is visible). I also want to make sure the pop-ups continue to work.

I tried code from a [Mapbox](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/updating-choropleth/) example, but I do not want the visibility of the legends to be dependent on zoom level.

If anyone can help troubleshoot this issue, I would greatly appreciate it. I have tried various ways to solve the problem, but have come up short on a solution.

**Here is the code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>GEO Core</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.5.1/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.5.1/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
<style>
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#map { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<style>

    #menu {
        background: #fff;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 10px;
        right: 10px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        width: 120px;
        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    }

    #menu a {
        font-size: 13px;
        color: #404040;
        display: block;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        padding: 10px;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
        text-align: center;
    }

    #menu a:last-child {
        border: none;
    }

    #menu a:hover {
        background-color: #f8f8f8;
        color: #404040;
    }

    #menu a.active {
        background-color: #007066;
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    #menu a.active:hover {
        background: #009586;
    }

    .mapboxgl-popup {
        max-width: 400px;
        font: 12px/20px 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    .legend {
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 3px;
        bottom: 30px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        font: 12px/20px 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        padding: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        right: 10px;
        z-index: 1;
        line-height: 18px;
    }
 
    .legend h4 {
        margin: 0 0 10px;
    }
 
    .legend div span {
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 10px;
        margin-right: 5px;
        width: 10px;
    }

</style>

<nav id="menu"></nav>
<div id="map"></div>

<div id="lunginc-legend" class="legend">
    <h4>Lung Cancer Incidence</h4>
    <h4>Standardized Incidence Ratio</h4>
    <div><span style="background-color: #FE0000"></span>1.901-1.981</div>
    <div><span style="background-color: #FF4719"></span>1.601-1.900</div>
    <div><span style="background-color: #FF8932"></span>1.401-1.600</div>
    <div><span style="background-color: #FEB54E"></span>1.201-1.400</div>
    <div><span style="background-color: #FFE864"></span>1.101-1.200</div>
    <div><span style="background-color: #D9D9D9"></span>0.901-1.100</div>
    <div><span style="background-color: #4AB9E7"></span>0.801-0.900</div>
    <div><span style="background-color: #349FE3"></span>0.701-0.800</div>
    <div><span style="background-color: #146DBD"></span>0.601-0.700</div>
    <div><span style="background-color: #014CA9"></span>0.494-0.600</div>
</div>

<div id="minority-legend" class="legend">
    <h4>Percent Minority</h4>
    <div><span style="background-color: #0571B0"></span>0-20%</div>
    <div><span style="background-color: #92C5DE"></span>21-40%</div>
    <div><span style="background-color: #F7F7F7"></span>41-60%</div>
    <div><span style="background-color: #F4A582"></span>61-80%</div>
    <div><span style="background-color: #CA0020"></span>81-100%</div>
</div>

<script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZ2VvbWN3IiwiYSI6ImNrdG4wMTgwMTE0enEydW82bDI3OTE4MG8ifQ.ZsnWiaE-fcwT_N4CPtLbPQ';
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10',
        zoom: 6,
        center: [-89.5, 45.0]
    });

    // Wait until the map has finished loading.
    map.on('load', () => {

        // Add a custom raster tileset source.
        map.addSource('lunginc', {
            type: 'raster',
            url: 'mapbox://geomcw.cpq2pmak'
        });
        map.addLayer({
            'id': 'Lung Cancer Incidence',
            'type': 'raster',
            'source': 'lunginc',
            'source-layer': 'lunginc1015z14-76a5nb',
            'layout': {
                // Make the layer visible by default.
                'visibility': 'visible'
            },
            'paint': {
                'raster-opacity': 0.5
            }
        });

        // Add a custom vector tileset. 
        map.addSource('ejwi', {
            type: 'vector',
            url: 'mapbox://geomcw.dp29nekw'
        });
        map.addLayer({
            'id': 'Percent Minority',
            'type': 'fill',
            'source': 'ejwi',
            'source-layer': 'EJWI2016-8zomjk',
            'layout': {
                // Make the layer not visible by default.
                'visibility': 'visible'
            },
            'paint': {
                'fill-color': [
                    'interpolate',
                    ['linear'],
                    ['get', 'MINORPCT'],
                    0.2,
                    '#0571B0',
                    0.4,
                    '#92C5DE',
                    0.6,
                    '#F7F7F7',
                    0.8,
                    '#F4A582',
                    1.0,
                    '#CA0020'
                ],
                'fill-opacity': 0.75
            }
        });
    });

    // After the last frame rendered before the map enters an "idle" state.
    map.on('idle', () => {

        // If these layers were not added to the map, abort
        if (!map.getLayer('Lung Cancer Incidence') || !map.getLayer('Percent Minority')) {
            return;
        }

        // Enumerate ids of the layers.
        const toggleableLayerIds = ['Lung Cancer Incidence', 'Percent Minority'];

        // Set up the corresponding toggle button for each layer.
        for (const id of toggleableLayerIds) {
            // Skip layers that already have a button set up.
            if (document.getElementById(id)) {
                continue;
            }

            // Create a link.
            const link = document.createElement('a');
            link.id = id;
            link.href = '#';
            link.textContent = id;
            link.className = 'active';

            // Show or hide layer when the toggle is clicked.
            link.onclick = function (e) {
                const clickedLayer = this.textContent;
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();

                const visibility = map.getLayoutProperty(clickedLayer,'visibility');

                // Toggle layer visibility by changing the layout object's visibility property.
                if (visibility === 'visible') {
                    this.className = '';
                    map.setLayoutProperty(clickedLayer, 'visibility', 'none');
                } else {
                    this.className = 'active';
                    map.setLayoutProperty(clickedLayer,'visibility','visible');
                }
            };

            const layers = document.getElementById('menu');
            layers.appendChild(link);
        }
    });

    // Open popup at location of click. 
    map.on('click', 'Percent Minority', (e) => {
        new mapboxgl.Popup()
            .setLngLat(e.lngLat)
            .setHTML((e.features[0].properties.MINORPCT*100).toFixed(2))
            .addTo(map);
    });

    // Change the cursor to a pointer.
    map.on('mouseenter', 'Percent Minority', () => {
        map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';
    });

    // Change the cursor back to hand.
    map.on('mouseleave', 'Percent Minority', () => {
        map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the actual problem you're having? Mapbox does not have a concept of "legends". So, is the problem about working out whether a layer is visible? Try to narrow down the specific issue, not just the overall goal.

Comment: Let me see if I can clarify. The visibility of the layers is not the issue. The code to toggle layers works, but there is no additional information on what the image displays (hence, the need for a legend). I found a Mapbox example on how to create legends, but the display of the legend is based on zoom level. I need the legend to be displayed based on the layer selected. My question is does code exist in Mapbox GL JS to toggle multiple elements together (the layer and the legend) when one element is selected to be visible?

Comment: As I said, legends don't exist within Mapbox. So, no, Mapbox does not provide anything to toggle legends alongside anything else. I also don't know what you mean by "one element is selected to be visible" - "element" is not a Mapbox term. Suggest you read through the documentation.

Comment: I realized I am using "legend" as a proxy for "div" tags (apologies, I'm not familiar with the terminology). I think this is less of a Mapbox issue and more of a JS issue. I've been through the Mapbox documentation several times and have found it unhelpful. To re-word my goal again (at the risk of being repetitive and unclear), I am looking for a solution that would allow div tags (which hold the content of the "legend") to become visible when a specific map layer is visible.

Comment: So which of those two things is the problem? Making a div tag visible? Or detecting when a specific map layer is visible? You need to break down your goal to the actual bit you have a problem with. Not simply state "here's what I'm trying to do, help me do it".